# Ajax buggy bar with firefox

Tags: html, ajax

I encouter a problem with my Navbar on Firefox.
The problem is that my Navbar is flickering.. It's constantly growing and shrinking.

The problem do not appears on Chrome And Opera..

What causes this problem ?
My Ajax code here :

The data of this call is loaded, but the problem of flickering appears..(
Console Problem ? No at all

How should it appears ? : https://prnt.sc/s4pkme
Thanks for help

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: '../../ajax/getlastnamespaces.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        $('#resultlastprojects').html(response);

      }, error: function(data){
        ShowMessageNotification('error', 'Le chargement du tableau a échoué...', 4000, 'top-end');
      }


    });
  });
  </script>
```

More code here :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["connection"]) && ($_SESSION["role"] >= 0)){
$title_page = "DashBoard - j";
$anneeactuel = date("Y");
$anneeprecedente = strval(date("Y")-1);
require_once("../../include/js/ShowNotif.php");
require_once("../../include/head.php");
?>
  <!-- Main content -->
  <div class="main-content" id="panel">
    <!-- Topnav -->
    <?php
    require_once("../../include/navbar.php");
    ?>
    <div class="header bg-primary pb-6">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header-body">
          <div class="row align-items-center py-4">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-7">
              <h6 class="h2 text-white d-inline-block mb-0">DashBoard</h6>
              <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="d-none d-md-inline-block ml-md-4">
                <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-links breadcrumb-dark">
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Accueil</li>
                </ol>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          <script>

          $(document).ready(function(){
          $.ajax({
              url: '../../ajax/getnumberofnamespaces.php',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success: function(response){
                var nbrprojectsofthisyear = response[0][0];
                var nbrprojectsofprecedentyear = response[0][1];
                var nbrprojectstotal = response[0][2];
                var nbrprojectsparmois = response[1];
                myChart.data.datasets[0].data = response[1];
                myChart.data.labels = response[2];
                myChart.update();

                var pourcentageparrapportmoisdernier = response[3][0];
                var pourcentageanneederniere = response[3][1];
                var pourcentageanneesprecedente = response[3][2];
                $('#nbrprojectstotal').html(nbrprojectstotal);
                $('#nbrprojectsofthisyear').html(nbrprojectsofthisyear);
                $('#nbrprojectsofprecedentyear').html(nbrprojectsofprecedentyear);
                $('#pourcentageparrapportmoisdernier').html(pourcentageparrapportmoisdernier);

                if(pourcentageparrapportmoisdernier <= 1){
                  $("#colortext").attr('class', 'mr-2 text-danger');
                  $("#sensfleche").attr('class', 'fa fa-arrow-down');
                }

                $('#pourcentageanneederniere').html(pourcentageanneederniere);
                if(pourcentageanneederniere <= 1){
                  $("#colortextpourcentageparrapportmoisdernier").attr('class', 'mr-2 text-danger');
                  $("#sensflechepourcentageparrapportmoisdernier").attr('class', 'fa fa-arrow-down');
                }

                $('#pourcentageanneesprecedente').html(pourcentageanneesprecedente);
                if(pourcentageanneesprecedente <= 1){
                  $("#colortextpourcentageanneesprecedente").attr('class', 'mr-2 text-danger');
                  $("#sensflechepourcentageanneesprecedente").attr('class', 'fa fa-arrow-down');
                }

                ShowMessageNotification('success', 'Le chargement des graphiques a réussi !', 4000, 'top-end');


              }, error: function(html){
                ShowMessageNotification('error', 'Le chargement des graphiques a échoué...', 4000, 'top-end');
              }

            });


          });




          </script>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <!-- Card body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">NameSpaces</h5>
                      <span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0" id="nbrprojectstotal">LoadingProcess...</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <div class="icon icon-shape bg-gradient-red text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                        <i class="ni ni-chart-bar-32"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="mt-3 mb-0 text-sm">
                    <span id="colortext" class="text-success mr-2"><i id="sensfleche" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span id="pourcentageparrapportmoisdernier">LoadingProcess...</span>%</span>
                    <span class="text-nowrap">/ Mois dernier</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <!-- Card body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">Nouveaux NameSpaces en <?= $anneeactuel; ?></h5>
                      <span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0" id="nbrprojectsofthisyear">LoadingProcess...</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <div class="icon icon-shape bg-gradient-info text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                        <i class="ni ni-spaceship"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="mt-3 mb-0 text-sm">
                    <span id="colortextpourcentageanneederniere" class="text-success mr-2"><i id="sensflechepourcentageanneederniere" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span id="pourcentageanneederniere">LoadingProcess...</span>%</span>
                    <span class="text-nowrap">/ Année précedente</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card card-stats">
                <!-- Card body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-muted mb-0">Nouveaux NameSpaces en <?= $anneeprecedente; ?></h5>
                      <span class="h2 font-weight-bold mb-0" id="nbrprojectsofprecedentyear">LoadingProcess...</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <div class="icon icon-shape bg-gradient-primary text-white rounded-circle shadow">
                        <i class="ni ni-chart-pie-35"></i>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p class="mt-3 mb-0 text-sm">
                    <span id="colortextpourcentageanneesprecedente" class="text-success mr-2"><i id="sensflechepourcentageanneesprecedente" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> <span id="pourcentageanneesprecedente">LoadingProcess...</span>%</span>
                    <span class="text-nowrap">/ Années précedentes</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>



          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div class="container-fluid mt--6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card bg-default">
            <div class="card-header bg-transparent">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <h6 class="text-dark text-uppercase ls-1 mb-1">Vue Globale</h6>
                  <h5 class="h3 text-dark mb-0">NameSpaces déployés</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item mr-2 mr-md-0" data-toggle="chart" data-target="#mycanvas" data-prefix="$" data-suffix="k">
                      <a class="nav-link py-2 px-3 active" data-toggle="tab">
                        <span class="d-none d-md-block">Mois</span>
                        <span class="d-md-none">M</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- Chart -->
              <div class="chart">
                <!-- Chart wrapper -->
                <canvas id="mycanvas" class="chart-canvas"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="resultlastprojects"></div>

      <!-- Footer -->
      <?php
      require_once("../../include/footer.php");
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Argon Scripts -->
  <!-- Core -->
  <?php
  require_once("../../include/js/js.php");
  ?>

  <script>



  // create initial empty chart
  var ctx_live = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx_live, {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            color: Charts.colors.gray[700],
            zeroLineColor: Charts.colors.gray['rgb(249,249,249)'],

          },
          ticks: {

          }
        }]
      },
    },
    data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Avr', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juil', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'NameSpaces ',
        data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      }]
    }
  });





  </script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: '../../ajax/getlastnamespaces.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response){
        $('#resultlastprojects').html(response);

      }, error: function(data){
        ShowMessageNotification('error', 'Le chargement du tableau a échoué...', 4000, 'top-end');
      }


    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else{
  header('Location: ../../connect.php');
} ?>
```

[image: Buggy bar]

Answer (score 0):

Solved : The problem is that two files JS was loaded. One in my php page, and another from the AJAX call ( that was returning a js file too :) )